# creating unit testing with phantomjs on VPS server

Tags: java, shell, selenium, phantomjs

I created a java application (JFrame) to test a web application using phantomjs and selenium, and my test is working as expected, the java application allows me to solve login captcha by taking screenshot from phantomjs and rendering it into java application for me and also allows me to upload and download files.

Now I have got a new task, and it requires me to run the test in CentOS VPS and controlled by the same java application from user end on internet, so I am little confused about it and not know how could I will achieve that.

I have an idea that I would like to share with you all, that is to run shell command from java to invoke the java application on CentOS VPS, but than how can I continue with the same command shell session because the java app requires continuity and yes if any change is required in the java application I am ready to bear that but I have no idea to maintain the same session when executing shell command from outside the VPS.

As I said earlier the java application allows to solve login captcha and allows to upload files, so when java app offers captcha image to user, than user type the captcha and presses the enter key and than the java application process the input by user and fill it to the login form using phantomjs and selenium and same goes for the file uploads. so my question is :

`How could I can achieve that? or I need to install desktop on the VPS to run same java application on VPS? as using JFrame and its requires GUI.`

any help or suggestion would be a great help for me, thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: How do you run it now? Java, Selenium and PhantomJS are available for CentOS so as long as the configuration is correct, the code should work just fine.

Comment: everything is configured and working properly... but as I said the java application will be on local machine different from VPS and the phantomjs will be on VPS , while locally everything is working properly.

Comment: So you need access from the VPS to your local machine, either via VPN or over the internet. Then, just give PhantomJS the proper URL. As long as the application is totally accessible from the VPS, PhantomJS will work as expected.

Comment: no from local machine to VPS, and local machine will be responsible for starting the java application and providing the input for the application that it started on the VPS, how to maintain the session continuously ...

Comment: @makeMonday the VPS has no desktop and I had not tried running the app on the VPS but i have done the configuration for java and phantomjs and tried a simple JFrame application and it says no GUI is set.. so what would you say will it work if I will install desktop on the VPS. please help cause I dont want to messup with the VPS

Comment: It is probably an issue with the JFrame Application, since PhantomJS does not need any GUI. I would say that it might work with a desktop, but it is up to the dependencies of the application.

Comment: actually the jframe application is a simple gui app that has some buttons and input fields and on pressing the button it start the phantomjs and get the web application to test it. and only requires jdk installed to run.. any way thanks a lot for your important time.